# 500 Internal Server error when activating gateway aws Lumen

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lumen

I am uploading my lumen API on AWS using bref.
Everything is deployed well. But, on testing the API Gateway it always gives error **500: Internal error**

this is my **serverless.yml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: App
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  phpserver:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-phpserver
      Description: PHP Webserver
      CodeUri: .
      Runtime: provided
      Handler: public/index.php
      MemorySize: 3008
      Timeout: 30
      Tracing: Active
      Layers:
        - !Sub arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:209497400698:layer:php-73-fpm:1
      Events:
        api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
```

**Log**

> [05-Sep-2019 19:06:06] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 10
>
> [05-Sep-2019 19:06:06] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
>
> START RequestId: 3aa27f9b-4c14-4a3d-b2f4-c365972cb921 Version: $LATEST
>
> END RequestId: 3aa27f9b-4c14-4a3d-b2f4-c365972cb921
>
> REPORT RequestId: 3aa27f9b-4c14-4a3d-b2f4-c365972cb921 Init Duration: 276.63 ms    Duration: 149.14 ms Billed Duration: 500 ms Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 100 MB
> XRAY TraceId: 1-5d715c9d-891bf843b6af8c6b55df7c22   SegmentId: 759577045ee42756

Can someone explain why is this happening and how to fix this?
I am really new to this.
Thankyou in Advance!